# Loop through localStorage and show specific value on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I need to make a shopping cart for my library project the issue here is that on a click of a certain book I cannot add it in another localStorage.

```
This is my html    <!--Knjige-->
<div class="container grid" id='knjige'></div>
```

**This is my CSS:**

```
.container{
    margin: 50px;   }

  .grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-items: start;   }

  .grid-card{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: orange;
    z-index: 9;   }

  .text:hover{
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;   }

  .text{
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;   }
```

**And this is my JavaScript, please note that I'm not allowed to use jQuery**

```
let knjige = [

    {"Naziv":"4_50 From Paddington_ A Miss Marple Mystery",
    "ID":"XA7JORPL",
    "Autor":"Agatha Christie",
    "Godina":"2007",
    "Cena":546,
    "Raspolozivo_stanje":50,
    },

    {"Naziv":"Lord Edgware Dies (1986, Berkley)",
    "ID":"BPL6QUG5",
    "Autor":"Agatha Christie",
    "Godina":"1986",
    "Cena":1041.06,
    "Raspolozivo_stanje":15,
    },

    {"Naziv":"Murder at the Vicarage  (2000, Signet)",
    "ID":"T2CGKTQQ",
    "Autor":"Agatha Christie",
    "Godina":"2000",
    "Cena":546,
    "Raspolozivo_stanje":44,
    },

    {"Naziv":"Sparkling Cyanide (1989)",
    "ID":"1QIFZZ4P",
    "Autor":"Agatha Christie",
    "Godina":"1989",
    "Cena":1114.91,
    "Raspolozivo_stanje":45,
    },

    {"Naziv":"The Mystery of the Blue Train",
    "ID":"4C4XW7H2",
    "Autor":"Agatha Christie",
    "Godina":"1928",
    "Cena":1041.06,
    "Raspolozivo_stanje":"",
    }
    ];

    if(!localStorage.getItem('knjige')){
        window.localStorage.setItem('knjige', JSON.stringify(knjige));
    }

    let knjigeLocalStorage = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('knjige'));

    window.onload = function(show){
        for(knjiga of knjigeLocalStorage){
            show += `
                <div class='grid-card'>
                    <div class='text'>
                        <h4>Naziv: ${knjiga.Naziv}</h4>
                        <p>Autor: ${knjiga.Autor}</p>
                        <p>ID: ${knjiga.ID}</p>
                        <p>Godina: ${knjiga.Godina}</p>
                        <p>Cena: ${knjiga.Cena}</p>
                        <p>Raspolozivo Stanje: ${knjiga.Raspolozivo_stanje}</p>
                        <button class='btn' id='dugme' onclick=''><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        };
        document.getElementById('knjige').innerHTML = show;
    };
```

So basically what I want is when I click on that button to show value of that specific book, hope I was clear..

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't put that in the localStorage yet but I've tried and all I can loop through is the whole localStorage. 

So basically every card has it's own button for adding that specific book in the localStorage, here's my github: https://github.com/Elvis339/Biblioteka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a mis-typed value here: `for(knjiga of knjigeLocalStorage){`
2. innerHTML is going to give you all sorts of
   problems with your onclick events and rendering html

I prefer to use addEventListener and adding elements via the DOM. It's a bit old school.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const div = document.getElementById('knjige');

    knjigeLocalStorage.forEach((k) => {

    const d = document.createElement("div");
    d.classList.add("grid-card");
    const text = document.createElement("div");
    text.classList.add("text");
    const h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    h4.innerHTML = `Naziv ${k.Naziv}`;
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    const i = document.createElement("i");
    i.classList.add("fas", "fa-shopping-cart");
    button.appendChild(i);

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {

        alert(`Naziv ${k.Naziv}`);

    });


    text.append(h4);
    text.append(button);
    d.appendChild(text);
    div.appendChild(d);
  });

});
```

Try this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2cor9v1w/

[document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) Doesn't work for me with JSFiddle, but you may need it for your actual code to replace window.onload.